# Checking if two variables either both not null or both null

Tags: powershell

I have been developing a script to send mail based on variables. I have a script like below.

Each of these 2 variables may be `$null` or not `$null`. What's the best practice to check for such condition?

Here is my script:

```
$variableA = ""
$variableB = ""

if($variableA) {
  Write-Host "mail send variableA"
} else {
  Write-Host "mail not send variableA"
}

if($variableB) {
  Write-Host "mail  send variableB"
} else {
  Write-Host "mail not send variableB"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use negated `-xor` operator:

```bsh
# Either both nulls or both have values
(-not (($null -eq $a) -xor ($null -eq $b)))
```

One can disagree what's more readable. I'd personally just go with more explicit formula:

```bsh
(($null -eq $a) -and ($null -eq $b)) -or 
(($null -ne $a) -and ($null -ne $b))
```

Remember to put `$null` in the left side of the comparison, it's considered as a [best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Thanks , btw  Each of these 2 variables may be not null or null.  How do I check this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, use `-eq`/`-ne` and [logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7). Please specify your question if that wasn't what you mean.

Comment: @Arbelac Your question title clearly states two cases: both variables are `$null` or both variables are not `$null`. So the negation of an exclusive or operation is the way to go as robdy correctly stated.